# Difference between #include<large.cu> and #include"large.cu"

Tags: visual-studio-2008, cuda

I wanted to know where does VS 2008 look for file if it is in the form

```
#include<large.cu>
```

Also, where does it look if in the form

```
#include"large.cu"
```

Also, suppose I have 2 files under the same project and I want file a to know about the functions in file b, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case the file is located in the default directory of the compiler/IDE. As @Casey points out if you add directories to the IDE's path these will also be searched when looking for include files in this format.

In the second case the file is located in the same directory as your source files.

To add a directory to the IDE's path select **Tools > Options... > Projects and Solutions > VC++ Directories** then add a new directory to the list box on that page. Assuming cuda looks in those directories of course.

Comment: How to modify the default directory. how do i find what the default directory is. can i change it through vs?

Comment: @Programmer - as @Casey points out you can add new directories to the IDE and these will be picked up by the `<>` format.

Comment: How do i add new directories to the IDE

Answer (score 0):

In addition to ChrisF's answer, the first case is also if you have a C/C++ directory path setup for the project.

Comment: how to set up c++ directory path. also, do also header files in my vs project need to go in separate folder , not source